# Meteor session namespace

Tags: session, meteor

Is there a way to namespace Meteor.js Session? In larger applications can happen I accidentally replace existing session. If I use namespaced session, this chance is lower.

Only solution in current implementation that comes to my mind is:

```
Session.set('namespace1Value');
Session.set('namespace2Value');
```

I would like to do something like:

```
var sectionFoo = Session.section('foo');
sectionFoo.set('bar');
```

Is Meteor going to support Session namespaces?

Comment: Could the namespace 'foo' just be kept as another session variable?  Then `Session.set( Session.get('namespace') + 'bar', value_for_foo_bar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you want.  If you find it useful, you may want to package it and publish it to Atmosphere.

```
_.extend(Session, {
  /**
   * Returns a wrapper around Session
   * which automatically prepends
   * the specified name to all keys.
   *
   * @method namespace
   * @param {String} name Name of namespace
   * @param {String} [separator] Separator for prepended
   *                 name. Default is '-'
   * @return {Object} Namespaced session object
   */
  namespace: function (name, separator) {
    var ns;

    separator = separator || '-';
    ns = name + separator;

    return {
      get: function (key) {
        return Session.get(ns + key);
      },
      set: function (key, value) {
        return Session.set(ns + key, value);
      },
      setDefault: function (key, value) {
        return Session.setDefault(ns + key, value);
      },
      equals: function (key, value) {
        return Session.equals(ns + key, value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGQ-ax5cFnk) talk, local reactive state will be part of Meteor UI which we can expect for Meteor 1.0 (due out early 2014). For now, I just use long session variable names.